# How can i make a guild-side variable using Discord.js

Tags: discord, discord.js

im trying to make a server/guild side variable for my bot (have a variable that has a different value in each server). I dont know how to make that so i really need help... How can i get a variable to have a different value in each server?

Comment: Can you elaborate on your issue? More context will sure help someone who want to answer your question.

Comment: Create a dictionary with the key being the `id`s of your guilds and the keys being whatever information you want to save on a per guild basis.

Comment: @ShubhamParihar here is some more context as you requested: i want to make a "configure" command that can disable and enable certain commands. I would use a boolean variable that i can then use to disable certain commands. My problem is that i dont know how to have a variable that has a different value in each server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a discord.js [`Collection`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection), which is:

> A Map with additional utility methods. This is used throughout discord.js rather than Arrays for anything that has an ID, for significantly improved performance and ease-of-use.

A [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) object holds key-value pairs and remembers the original insertion order of the keys. Any value may be used as either a key or a value. Here's a quick demo:

```js
// let's say we had two people: John and Sarah
const people = new Map();

// each of them were a different age
people.set('John', 25); // in this example, 'John' is the key, and 25 is the value
people.set('Sarah', 19); // in this example, 'Sarah' is the key, and 25 is the value

// each person has an individual age
// you can `get()` the key, and it will return the value
console.log(`Sarah is ${people.get('Sarah')} years old.`);
console.log(`John is ${people.get('John')} years old.`);
```

You can use this type of format to create a collection with each key being a different guild ID, and each value being... whatever you want. Here's an example:

```js
// const { Collection } = require('discord.js');
const guilds = new Collection();

// put some data in an object as the key
guilds.set("Guild ID", {
  name: "Guild Name",
  welcomeMsg: "Welcome new person!",
  welcomeChannel: "...",
  blacklistedIDs: ["123456", "67890"],
});

client.on("guildMemberAdd", (member) => {
  const guild = guilds.get(member.guild.id); // get the collection element via guild id
  if (!guild) return;

  // then access all its data!
  console.log(`Somebody joined ${guild.name}`);
  if (guild.blacklistedIDs.includes(member.id)) return member.kick();
  guild.welcomeChannel.send(guild.welcomeMsg);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe Tin Nguyen posted this idea as a comment, I am just elaborating on that. To achieve what you want, you can use what is known as a "data dictionary" which is basically just a file storing a list of something.

For your specific use case, you can use a simple JSON file to store your variables. For each guild that your bot is in, you can add a new object to a list of objects in a local JSON file called `variable.json` for example.
Here is an idea of what it might look like:

```
[
    {
        "guild": "INSERT GUILD ID",
        "value": "INSERT VARIABLE VALUE"
    },
]
```

`guild` will store the id of the guild, so you can identify the correct `value`. To get the value stored in `value` for a certain guild, all you have to do is loop through the JSON file, and find the object with the correct guild ID:

```
const variables = require("variable.json");            //imports the JSON data
const value;                                           //creates a new variable
for (i = 0; i < variables.length; i++) {               //loops through the guilds
    if (variables[i].guild === message.guild.id) {     //if the IDs are the same...
        value = variables[i].value;                    //...sets "value" to the retrieved value
    }
}
```

This of course relies on the fact that your bot also adds each guild it joins to the list. To do this, you can use the `guildCreate` event. Documentation for this can be found [here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Client?scrollTo=e-guildCreate).

Comment: Instead of creating an entire `for` loop, you can just use `variables.find(({ guild }) => guild === message.guild.id)`